# Excel VBA - How to transfer/translate functions in a cell into a VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, function, cell

The cell function I currently  have is

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2)<2, LEFT(A2,2) &MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,3) &1000, LEFT(A2,4) &MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,3) &1000), LEFT(A2,4)&"1000")
```

I would like to create a VBA code for this so when I run it, it automatically performs this function on range A2:A140 and produce output in B2:B140 and highlights any duplicates.

[image: Excel Sheet Pic]

Comment: some sample to reproduce the issue would be useful

Comment: @Bharat I have attached a sample of what it looks like, let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: The TRUE part of your IF statement would return a `#VALUE!` error which is hidden by your `IFERROR`:  `IF(LEN(A2)<2,LEFT(A2,2)&MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,3)&1000)` - if the length of text is less than two (i.e one or none) then take the first two characters of A2 (which will return the only character) and then FIND the space..... which will cause an error unless the only character _is_ a space - then it will return 1000.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Sub transform()

  Range("B2:B140").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2)<2, LEFT(A2,2) &MID(A2,FIND("" "",A2,1)+1,3) &1000, LEFT(A2,4) &MID(A2,FIND("" "",A2,1)+1,3) &1000), LEFT(A2,4)& ""1000"")"
  
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Formula gets copied to all cells
[image]

**Edit 2:  Use SUBSTITUTE to remove the spaces**

```
 Sub transform()
   Range("B2:B140").Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(IF(LEN(A2)<2, LEFT(A2,2) &MID(A2,FIND("" "",A2,1)+1,3) &1000, LEFT(A2,4) &MID(A2,FIND("" "",A2,1)+1,3) &1000), LEFT(A2,4)& ""1000""),"" "","""")"
   
 End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what the OP meant, but it does do what they asked. :)

Comment: Apologise if it appeared just to give what asked than knowledge. May be I missed the part of intent

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you didn't miss any intent.  The OP said they had a function and want to automatically apply it to that range - your answer does exactly that.  I'm thinking they wanted something a bit more VBAish where the data may not always go to row 140, but the value still appears in column B if they update or add to the list and it doesn't place a formula in the cell but rather the final value... but they didn't ask for that.

Comment: @Bharat it only does it for the first line and then for the rest it just copy and pastes the formula into the cells, is there a method where each time it runs the formula it moves to the next cell and adjusts the formula to A3,A4, A5... and onwards.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yep, that is exactly what I'm looking for, sorry for not being clear in the question. I would like the final result of the formula to go to the Column B and it's corresponding cell number

Comment: @Ananya, formula works for all cells I tried it, I have attached the image

Comment: @Bharat haha, I for some reason didn't check it properly, but I put it into another sheet and it gave it all perfectly! Thank you so much. Do you by chance know how I can add onto this line of code and create something which can delete all unnecessary spaces in the column B?

Comment: Which space? I am not able to see, can you be more specific

Comment: @Bharat in the excel sheet you have posted a picture of, in cell B3 there is a space between  204 and Wel1000. I would like to get rid of those spaces for all of column B

Comment: Updated the answer for spaces